# How to Auto 'click' first row in DataTable on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a Jquery DataTable that I am loading SQL data into, this displays X amount of rows with this data, I can then click a row on the DataTable, and using Jquery, I populate inputs on the users screen.   Now, I want to be able to have the DataTable automatically 'click' on the first row upon loading, so it can populate these inputs with the first value (less human interaction).

Code Below:

```
<h1>My Table</h1>

<style>
  #myTable tr {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #myTable {
      width: 100px;
  }

  #myTable tbody tr:hover {
    background: #d7d7d7 !important;
  }

  #myTable td {
    background: transparent !important;
      width: 100px;
  }

  #myTable {
    margin-top: 6px;
  }

  #myTable_paginate .previous,
  #myTable_paginate .next {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin: auto 10px;
  }
  
</style>
<table id="myTable"></table>


<script>
  (() => {
    return true;
  })();

  function convertmyTableData(jsonData = {data: [{'none': ''}]}) {
    const mapped = [];

    const keys = [];
    Object.keys(jsonData.data[0]).forEach(key => keys.push({'title': key}));

    for (let option of jsonData.data) {

      const mappedOption = [];
      for (let key of Object.keys(option)) {
        if (option[key]) {
          mappedOption.push(option[key]);
        }
      }
      if (mappedOption.length > 0) {
        mapped.push(mappedOption);
      }
    }

    $('#myTable').dataTable({
      data: mapped,
      columns: keys,
      "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "sTitle": "Test"
        , "aTargets": ["myTable_records"]
      }, {
        "aTargets": [0]
        , "bSortable": true
        , "mRender": function (value, type, full) {
          return value;
        }
      }]
    });

      $('#myTable').dataTable( {
          "autoWidth": true
      } );



    const clickRow = function (e) {
      var el = $('#myTable').dataTable();
      var iPos = el.fnGetPosition(this);
      var aData = el.fnGetData(iPos);

        $('#Input_1').val(aData[0]);
        $('#Input_2').val(aData[1]);
   
    }

    $("#myTable").on("click", "tr", clickRow);

      $('#myTable').dataTable( {
          "autoWidth": true
      } );
  }



  function myTableLookup() {
    let ID = '2343242';

    fetch(`/spr/custom/ID/json/${ID}?myParameter=hello`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.ok);
          return response.json();

    }).then(jsonData => {
          console.log(jsonData);
      convertmyTableData(jsonData);

    }).catch(err => {
      console.warn('Error!', err);
    });
  }

  myTableLookup();
</script>
```

$("#myTable").on("click", "tr", clickRow); - is used for when I click on any given row, it gets the values and populates the required fields on screen.

I want this to happen automatically on load, and only to the first row [0].

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
$("#myTable>tbody>tr:first").trigger('click');
```

or try clicking with a delay with `setTimout`

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#myTable>tbody>tr:first").trigger('click'); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use focus() method.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#myTable").focus();
    //or document.getElementById("myTable").focus();
   });
```